# Change summary type in Crystal Report cross tab to pick the exact value of the formula field

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

[image]

My problem here is that I want to display the value in formula (summary) as shown in the first image exactly. But I am forced to choose from the list of options (sum, average, count....)

Can this be done?

Comment: you need to use calculated summary.. try that

Comment: I have an older version: the 2004 version

Comment: Have you tried to insert calculated summary

Comment: I donot have that option in CR XI